# Keep ASP.Net session alive during Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does Ajax calls made through $.get (JQuery) keep the Asp.Net session state alive?
I have noticed that the request contains the asp.net session cookie. Does that mean the sliding session expiration timeout is reset every time you hit a controller action with an Ajax $.get request?

I know it works this way for conventional full page requests (NON Ajax)?

In my case I am making a series of Ajax calls to partial MVC3 views

Comment: Yes, but set if you want to confirm, set your sliding window really small and check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,
From my understanding any request to the Web Server will keep the Sessions Alive.
Javascript is used to create a standard request and captures the response so that you can update the UI elements on the screen.